# Не получается распараллелить потоки WINAPI

Tags: c, многопоточность, winapi

Программа начинает виснуть после того как я передаю переменную для поиска. В чем может быть проблема?
функция  Thread

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int *a;
int z,n,b1;


int dyrak1();
int dyrak2();
int dyrak3();
void SortMass(int*, int);
DWORD WINAPI Thread(LPVOID* ptr );


int main(void) {





int i,y1;

printf("Enter the number of items:\n");
 n = dyrak1();
a = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

printf("Enter item: \n");
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ",i+1);
        a[i] = dyrak2();

    }

printf("You want to sort?\n");
printf("Enter 1 if yes \n");
printf("Enter 0 if not \n");

while(scanf("%d", &y1)!=1||(y1!=1 && y1!=0))
            {
                printf("Error! Enter 1 if yes or 0 if no\n");
                fflush(stdin);
            }

if (y1==1)
{
    SortMass(a,n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
    printf("\n");
}
else
{
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                printf("%d ", a[i]);
            }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("Input variable 'a' for search: ");
z = dyrak3();

DWORD idThread;
     // дескриптор потока
     HANDLE firstThread;
     firstThread = CreateThread(NULL // нет защиты потока
      , 0 // размер стека
      , Thread // эта функция потока
      , (LPVOID)NULL // первая половина
      , CREATE_SUSPENDED // поток не запускается
      , &idThread // идентификатор потока
      );
     WaitForSingleObject(firstThread, INFINITE);


if (b1 != -1)
{
    printf("The index of the element is %d\n", b1+1);
}
else
    printf("The element isn't found!\n");

free(a);
getchar();getchar();
return 0;

}


void SortMass(int* m, int n)
{
     for(int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
       for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
       {
               if(m[j] > m[j+1])
               {
                       int foo = m[j];
                       m[j] = m[j+1];
                       m[j+1] = foo;
               }
       }
}
DWORD WINAPI Thread(LPVOID* ptr )
{


    int low, high, middle;
    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if (z < a[middle])
            high = middle - 1;
        else if (z > a[middle])
            low = middle + 1;
        else
        {
            b1=middle;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    b1 = -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поток создан с атрибутом `CREATE_SUSPENDED`, а значит он не запустится сам. Для запуска нужно вызвать функцию [ResumeThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms685086(v=vs.85).aspx), либо убрать этот флаг.